# How does $u$-$v$ symmetry hold for 2D conformal blocks?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

The explicit solution for the conformal blocks that appear in the $\phi$ 4-point function is
$$
g_{\Delta,\ell}(z,\bar z)\sim k_{\Delta+\ell}(z)k_{\Delta-\ell}(\bar z) + k_{\Delta+\ell}(\bar z)k_{\Delta-\ell}(z)
$$
where
$$
k_\alpha(x) = x^{\alpha/2}\ {}_2 F_1\left(\frac\alpha2, \frac\alpha2, \alpha; x\right)
$$
and ${}_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function. Now normally we parameterise the conformal block by the cross-ratios $u, v$ rather than the coordinates $z, \bar z$. They are related by
$$
u=z\bar z
\\v = (1-z)(1-\bar z)
$$

I know that $g_{\Delta,\ell}$ is supposed to satisfy $g_{\Delta,\ell}(u,v)=g_{\Delta,\ell}(u/v, 1/v)$, at least for $\ell$ even. However my calculations don't seem to match up.

Let's take the example of $z=1/2, \bar z = 3/5$, i.e. $u=0.3, v=0.2$. So $u/v = 1.5, 1/v = 5$ and mapping back to $z,\bar z$ gives $z=-1.5,\bar z = -1$ for the symmetric block.

But if $\ell = 0$ (even) and the conformal dimension of the intermediate operator $\Delta$ is not an even integer, then $g_{\Delta,\ell}(u,v)$ is real while $g_{\Delta,\ell}(u/v, 1/v)$ is complex (we have a negative number to a real power in $k_{\Delta}(z)$). I know that $\Delta$ can be allowed to vary continuously. So how are they supposed to match?

Have I misinterpreted the symmetry equation or the interconversion between $u,v$ and $z,\bar z$? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: For a start, $\bar z$ should be the complex conjugate of $z$, which is not true in your example.